# Animating a view inside a uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have nested tableviews so that I can have a sideways scrolling tableview in each of my tableview's cells.  I want to add an animation to the top row, that basically moves a view back and forth.  It is working, kind of:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (BannerCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: 100];
                             cell.handView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.handView.frame.origin.x-100, cell.handView.frame.origin.y, 32, 32);
                             cell.handView.alpha = 0.0f;

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
    }
    else cell.handView.hidden = YES;

    return cell;

}
```

This is working except on the first time my tableview loads, the view that I want animating doesn't even show up, when I scroll to a new cell and back to the first cell then it shows up an animates fine.  Not sure why it wouldn't run as expected on the first load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this delegate method actually being called? Because the actual delegate method that does this has the following signature:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Your method is returning a `UITableViewCell` object. I don't seem to find a delgate method like this.

Comment: Method is getting called.  I switched to your method, same issue.  It does work, just not on the first load of the tableview, I have to scroll down and back to the first cell.

Comment: And the method is getting called on view load, I verified that as well, instead of animating, it is just removing the view completely

Comment: First you should use the method that I told. It's the UiTableViewDelegate method which the TableView automatically call. You don't have to call this. 

Second, because you are doing your animation BEFORE the cell is displayed you dont see it first time.

Comment: I see that, unfortunately what I really need is didEndDisplayingCell but it is an iOS 6+ method which won't cut it.  Thanks for the help.